# How do I remove a specific part of a string?

Tags: python, string, pandas, substring

I'd like to remove a specific part of a string within a pandas df. More precisely, I want the script to remove everything within '(' and ')'.
Example:

```
'3453(s656)s(657)' -script-> '3453s'
```

Is there an easy implemented python function or need I to script it by my self?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should try a regex expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `str.replace`. Here's an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['3453(s656)s(657)', 'another(---)string']})

df['col1'] = df.col1.str.replace(r'(\(.*?\))', '')
        col1
0          3453s
1  anotherstring
```

Answer (score 0):

you could implement a simple python function to do just the following as:

```
def speclace(a)
    x=""
    s=0
    for i in a:
        if i=='(':
            s=1
        elif i==')':
            s=0
        elif s==0:
            x+=i
return x
```

<-- Upvote if helpful -->